# How can I define two model in html with AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new with AngularJs

if I want to define two model in html

how do I define it?

I haved tried it much times

please help

```
<body ng-app="experiment">
<div  ng-controller="functionCrtl" id="staff"> 
<div ng-modle="data1.data">
   <ng-view></ng-view>  
</div>
```

```
<div ng-app="experiment_left">
<div ng-controller="accordtionCrtl">
    <div ng-model="accordtion.accordtion">
      <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
experiment.config (function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider.when("/",{
templateUrl : "function1.html",
controller: 'functionCrtl'});
```

I want to dynamic load two page , how can I do?

Comment: Can we see what you've done so far? We're not here to give you the code but help with what you already have.

Comment: Where is your Controller?

Answer (score 0):

But to answer your question read this http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.

**Controller:**

```
 angular.module('myApp').controller('CreateUserCtrl', function ($scope) {

         $scope.firstname = 'John';
         $scope.surname = 'Doe';
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form ng-controller="CreateUserCtrl">
     <input ng-model="firstname " type="text" placeholder="firstname">
     <input ng-model="surname" type="text" placeholder="surname">
</form>
```